# How can i set a delay function in eventlister javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, delay

I have the words 'hey' and 'bye' that now blink but i want them to blink indivually from eachother, now they blink at the same time

How do i add a delay for the second one?

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('hey');
    setInterval(function() {
        f.style.display = (f.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
    }, 1000);

}, false);

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var b = document.getElementById('bye');
    setInterval(function() {
        b.style.display = (b.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
    }, 1000,);

}, false);
```

Comment: If you want for the second interval to start later (with a delay) look for `setTimeout`

Comment: Put one of the setIntervals inside a setTimeout of half the ms.
`window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var b = document.getElementById('bye');
    setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            b.style.display = (b.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
        }, 1000);
    }, 500);
}, false);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put one of the setIntervals inside a setTimeout of half the ms.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var b = document.getElementById('bye');
    setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            b.style.display = (b.style.display == 'none' ? '' : 'none');
        }, 1000);
    }, 500);
}, false);
```